# How do I add a JavaScript result to a static HTML href attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

if I have a JavaScript method called `getSomeStringValue()`, is there a way to pull that value and use it as the `href` of a link, something like as follows?

(I'm aware the following code does **not** work.)

```
<a href="$:getSomeStringValue()" target="_blank">
    My Link
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this:

```
<a href="javascript:getSomeStringValue()" target="_blank">
    My Link
</a>
```

And in `getSomeStringValue()` you can do:

```
function getSomeStringValue(){
   //some code
   window.location = somewhere;
}
```

Comment: `is there a way to pull that value and use it as the href of a link` I think he wants to set the gref to the value that `getSomeStringValue()` returns, not to execute the function on click.

Comment: @Chad thats why there is the `window.location` at the end of the function

Comment: @Chad lol. i edited my post like 3 seconds after i made it. its just ur bad luck :-p

Comment: Will this respect `target="_blank"`?

Comment: @Chris, if the OP wants `target=_blank`, the OP has to do `window.open(...)`

Answer (score 6):

I think this would work:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" id="mylink">
    My Link
</a>

<script>
document.getElementById("mylink").href = getSomeStringValue();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the idea posted by @Neal, and tweaked it a bit.  This was the code I ended-up using if anyone's curious...

```
<a href="#" onclick="$:loadNewURL(parameter1, parameter2)">
    My Link
</a>

<script>
function loadNewURL(parameter1, parameter2) {
    var newURL = "http://";
    if (parameter1 == "Some Value")
        window.location = newURL + "/somepageA.aspx?detail=" + parameter2;
    else
        window.location = newURL + "/somepageB.aspx?info=" + parameter2;
}
</script>
```